# Google indexing issue with my site

Tags: html, header, indexing, search-engine

Google is not indexing the  tag or description of my website and generating it's own based on the URL.

Here's a link to the search result:
https://www.google.com/#fp=771e16ed773001d1&q=mediatree&safe=off

Also, here's the HTML header.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Since 1995, MediaTree has been the leader in providing both innovative promotions and flexible solutions that are designed to motivate and reward consumer behavior. MediaTree's promotional strategies help drive performance and increase brand loyalty by offering recipients the latest in digital promotions and cutting-edge incentives. From Music Downloads to Movie Tickets there's a reward to fit any demographic or industry. ">
<title>MediaTree: Custom Branded Music Download, Movie Ticket, Magazine Subscription Cards and more!</title>

        <!-- CSS -->

    ...
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your http://www.mediatreegroup.com/robots.txt file say this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Which basically tells search engines they should not visit any pages on the site - so Google obeys and doesn't visit the pages and thus doesn't read your meta description.

See here: [The Web Robots Pages](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Change that, ASAP to this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

if you want search engines to crawl everything, or RTM to find out what you should actually disallow.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you!

Comment: lol - no problem - we've all missed the basics when looking for the bigger problems :)